# Python: randomly assign one of two values

Tags: python

```
if losttwice <= 2:
    bet = _________  # <- Here
elif losttwice <= 5:
    bet = bet * 2
else:
    bet = startingbet
```

Can anyone help me to add one more thing to this? I would like to do a random 50% chance when `losttwice <= 2` (when I lost 1-2 times) for it to be `bet = startingbet` or `bet = bet * 2` based on 50% chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if losttwice <= 2:
    bet = random.choice((startingbet, bet*2))
```

Answer (score 2):

`if random.random() > 0.5:` (and `import random` on the top) might be useful. You should be able to figure it out based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a great module for generating pseudo-randomness. Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html). If you decide to use `random.choice`, the code would look like:

```
from random import choice
if losttwice <= 2:
    bet = choice((startingbet, 2 * bet))
elif losttwice <= 5:
    bet = bet * 2
else:
    bet = startingbet
```

Answer (score 0):

import random

```
if losttwice <= 2:
        if random.random() > 0.5:
            bet = startingbet
        else:
            bet = bet * 2
elif losttwice <= 5:
    bet = bet * 2
else:
    bet = startingbet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if losttwice <= 2:      
    bet = random.choice([staringbet, bet*2])
elif losttwice <= 5:
    bet = bet * 2
else:
  bet = startingbet
```